# Get item from array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have the following array of hashes:

```
arr = [
  { most_accessed: [1,2,3]},
  { most_voted: [1,2]}
]
```

I need to get hash values by the key.
I'm trying:

```
arr.map{|x| x[:most_accessed]}
```

But the result is: nil

How can I do that ?

Comment: Why do you have such a strange data structure to begin with? The answers below are unnecessarily complicated, due to you having such a weird data structure. Why not just: `data = {most_accessed: [1,2,3], most_voted: [1,2]}`? Then you can just do `data[:most_accessed]`.

Comment: Only one of your hashes contains a `:most_accessed` key. The result of your code *contains* a `nil`, because your input contains a hash that doesn't have the key you're after. You need to clearly state your desired outputs, as it stands we can only guess what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): your original data is not well-formed. It should be a single hash, not the array of hashes.

Though even for this input there are ways:

```
arr.map { |e| e[:most_accessed] }.compact
arr.detect { |e| e[:most_accessed] }[:most_accessed]
arr.group_by { |e| e[:most_accessed] }.keys.compact
```

But still, consider making a proper hash from the data in the first place and then deal with it:

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |h, acc|
  acc.merge!(h) { |k, v1, v2| v1 | v2 } # or v1 + v2
end[:most_accessed]
```

Comment: _It should be a single hash_ yei.

Answer (score 1):

The result is `nil` for the `most_voted` key, as you're iterating over the each hash in the array, there's only one key called `most_accessed`, if you want the values per key, then you can use `values`:

```
arr = [
  { most_accessed: [1,2,3]},
  { most_voted: [1,2]}
]
p arr.map { |hash| hash[:most_accessed] } # [[1, 2, 3], nil]
p arr.map &:values                        # [[[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2]]]
p arr.flat_map &:values                   # [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]
p arr.inject(:merge)[:most_accessed]      # [1, 2, 3]
p arr.inject(:merge)[:most_voted]         # [1, 2]
```

Comment: `arr.map { |hash| hash.values.flatten }` ⇒ `arr.flat_map(&:values)`.

Comment: but how can I get values based on key: most_accessed or most_voted ? directly

Comment: Using `values` you get the hash values for each key, do you want to pass them manually?

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @SebastianPalma yes, I need to pass them manually, like:  arr.most_accessed and return [1,2,3]

Comment: I did this and worked: arr.find { |hash| hash[:most_accessed] }.values.flatten

Comment: See mudasobwa's answer "It should be a single hash", anyways you can merge the hashes in the array and get a single one, there you can access them by their keys, see updated answer @gui12344455.

Comment: Really like that use of `inject` @SebastianPalma - not seen it used for that purpose before!

Comment: and this structure ? how can I achieve the same ? 

arr = [
  { :group=>:most_accessed, :values=>[1,2,3]},
  { :group=>:most_accessed, :values=>[1,2,3]}
]

Comment: That depends totally in the input you're using @gui12344455, and is a question different to this, if you've solved the problem on why the result for the key you're trying to access is `nil`, then you can accept an answer and create a new one, adding the input you're using, the output you want to get, and covering the most of the cases for it.